# How to force text to be Upper case except selective strings c#

Tags: string, toupper

C#:

```
string mystring = "Hello World. &amp; my name is &lt; bob &gt;. Thank You."
Console.Writeline(mystring.ToUpper())
```

I am trying to get all the text to be uppercase except--

```
&amp;  &lt;  &gt;
```

Because these are my encoding and the encoding wont work unless the text is lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split the string with a space, turn all the items not starting with `&` to upper and just keep the rest as is, and then join back into a string:

```
string mystring = "Hello World. &amp; my name is &lt; bob &gt;. Thank You.";
string result = string.Join(" ", mystring.Split(' ').Select(m => m.StartsWith("&") ? m : m.ToUpper()));
```

[image]

Another approach is to use a regex to match `&`, 1+ word chars and then a `;`, and match and capture other 1+ word char chunks and only turn to upper case the contents in Group 1:

```
var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(mystring, 
    @"&\w+;|(\w+)", m => 
           m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() :
           m.Value
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to ask you if there is a way of doing it without Linq because I am using a cut down version of c# in another Software. The second aproach works perfectly well.

Comment: The second option is using a Match evaluator. You may also define a separate method and pass it instead of the lambda expression.